# ANTLRWorks error compiling grammar: "syntax error: invalid char literal: INVALID"

Tags: unicode, antlr, grammar, lexical-analysis

I wrote a stub for a grammar (only matches comments so far), and it's giving me the error:

> syntax error: invalid char literal: <INVALID>

Moreover, I've tracked down the error to being in the following command:

```
... ~LINE_ENDING* ...
LINE_ENDING     : ( '\n' | '\r' | '\r\n');
```

Can someone help me fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `~` operator can only be applied to a set. In a lexer, the elements of a set are characters of an input stream. In other words, you can have this:

```
~(  'a'..'z'
|   'C'
|   '\r'
|   '\n'
)
```

But you can't have this because it's a *sequence* (of two characters) instead of a *set*.

```
~('\r\n')
```

The problem you encountered is an extension of this second case.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you get that error (I have no means of testing it myself at the moment). Perhaps the fact you're negating either a single char (`\r` or `\n`) or a double char (`\r\n`) is an issue?

What happens if you try:

```
SingleLineComment
    :   '//' (~LineBreakChar)* (NewLine | EOF)
    ;

LineBreakChar
    :   '\r' | '\n'
    ;

NewLine
    :   '\r'? '\n' | '\r'
    ;
```

?

Comment: This is interesting: i don't get the error when using `~('\r'|'\n')*` so it must be for that reason. I'll have to add a comment and maybe report this or something, thanks for the help!